# How to output excerpt and read more in ACF Post Object

Tags: php, wordpress

I display the news in a separate block using ACF Post Object. I need to display excerpt and read more button. Now I have displayed some text and a "Read more" button in a post in the admin panel. But they are not displayed, although I display excerpt in the code. How can i do this?
[image]

```js
<div class="news">
  <div class="news-title">
       <span><?php _e('News Feature', 'bluegfx'); ?></span>
       <p><?php esc_html_e($select_news->post_title); ?></p>
       <pclass="excerpt"><?php esc_html_e($select_news->post_excerpt); ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="news-img">
       <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $select_news->ID); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you are adding excerpt content, is not the place for excerpt. there is a different field to add excerpt. To get your data you need to use ```post_content```

Comment: How can I display excerpt with Read More button? Even when I add excerpt in the sidebar, the Read More button is not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show read more button you have to use HTML & PHP code like this,

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink( $select_news->ID ); ?>">Read More</a></p>
```

Place this code where you want to show the button.